# How to use Script bundle and Intellisense reference together

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification

how do I combine Script bundle of MVC application

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

and JavaScript reference directives for IntelliSense so that I do not need to specify a version number 2.0.3 explicitly like this:

```
///<reference path="jquery-2.0.3.js"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to give it the complete path of each scripts you want to refer.
Like this :

```
///<autosync enabled="true" /> 
///<reference path="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"/>
```

you can add it to the top of your script or in the global reference script:
~/Scripts/_references.js

you just have to drag and drop the script file in it to add the reference.

sometime you need to restart visual studio to refresh the intelisence if the 
"" is not present

Edited to explain my comment :
if you have 2 different version of jquery with different jquery-ui you can make 2 reference file like this :

```
file1.js:
 ///<reference path="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"/>
 ///<reference path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-2.1.1.js"/>

file2.js:
 ///<reference path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.3.js"/>
 ///<reference path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.1.1.js"/>
```

then reference the file1.js or the file2.js on each of your scripts depend on the version used on this script.
Because the intellisense can't know wish version you use in the bundle ...

more info :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx#ReferenceDirectives

i hope it help

Comment: Benoit, I want to avoid specifying a version number 2.0.3 in my js files --> I do not see how your answer helps in that direction.

Comment: I dont think this is possible ...
if you have meany differents files versions, you will have to refer the version you use in each script ...
You can also make reference script for each versions you have to add only one reference in each scripts...

Comment: nope - no different versions - I have just one version, but I want to keep my references up to date after i update jquery via NuGet.

Comment: Sory to tel you you will have to change it after each version change ... This will be a nice visual studio addon to make, but they'r nothing native ...

Comment: Cannot accept you reply as answer, Benoit: "will have to change it after each version change" -- this is what I want to avoid and questioning about.

Comment: hi, i found resharper that have addin for javascript intelisence, did you try it ?
 http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/